# CSS Selector with specific CSS attribute

Tags: html, css

I have an html page:

**CSS**

```
#id2{background-image:url(b.png);}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="id1" style="background-image:url(a.png);"></div>
<div id="id2"></div>
```

I want to select div with CSS attributes: background-image. For the div1, I can do:

```
div[style*='background-image']{....something....}
```

How can I do similar with div2? I want something looks like this:

```
div[background-image]{....something.....}
```

In my case (due to some reasons), I cannot use the ID or Class name.
My question is:

> In html page, there are many divs. Some divs were set background-image in style property, some divs were set background-image in CSS file, some divs were set background-image in style tags. I want to select all div that we set background-image.

Comment: Is there any dom structure that id2 follows?

Comment: In html page, there are many divs. Some divs were set background-image in style property, some divs were set background-image in CSS file, some divs were set background-image in style tags. I want to select all div that we set background-image.

Comment: I don't think there is a pure CSS solution. But it can be achieved with Javascript

Comment: JS is also ok. Please suggest for me how?

Comment: You can do this using JavaScript and get the computed style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this is enough, but you can somehow do something using jQuery

```js
if ($("#id2").css("background-image") != "none") {
  alert('present');
  //do something if present;
} else {
  alert('absent');
  //do something if absent;
}
```

```css
#id2 {
  background-image: url('https://s7d1.scene7.com/is/image/PETCO/cat-category-090617-369w-269h-hero-cutout-d?fmt=png-alpha');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id2">aw</div>
```

The problem with this is if you just use `url()`, it will still show **"present"**, although I haven't seen any `background-image` that uses only `url()`. And if you want to know why I used `none` as comparison, you can try alerting `$("#id2").css("background-image")`.

**Javascript Style**

```js
var someElement = document.getElementById("id2");
var currentBackgroundImage = someElement.currentStyle ? someElement.currentStyle.backgroundImage :
                              getComputedStyle(someElement, null).backgroundImage;

if (currentBackgroundImage != "none") {
  alert('present');
  //do something if present;
} else {
  alert('absent');
  //do something if absent;
}
```

```css
#id2 {
  background-image: url('https://s7d1.scene7.com/is/image/PETCO/cat-category-090617-369w-269h-hero-cutout-d?fmt=png-alpha');
}
```

```html
<div id="id2">aw</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how to write the code bellow in Pure JS: $("#id2").css("background-image") != "none". I don't want to use any library, because increase my addon size.

Comment: Added a javascript version

Answer (score 1):

> You can't do this with only css, you have to use javascript or jquery.
>   here for you `css()` in jquery is useful

please see below example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#id2, #id3{background-image:url(b.png);}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       var alldiv = $('div');
       for (i=0;i<alldiv.length;i++){
          if($(alldiv[i]).css("background-image") != "none"){
            $(alldiv[i]).css("background-color","green");
          }       
       }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<div id="id1" style="background-color:#ff0000">This is a paragraph.</div>
<div id="id2" style="background-color:#ff0000">This is a paragraph.</div>
<div id="id3" style="background-color:#ff0000">This is a paragraph.</div>

<button>Return background-color of p</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit: applying to all div**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `CSS selector` and some `jquery function`. Not possible with only CSS selectors.

```js
if($('#id2').css("background-color")){
    $('#id2').css('color','red');
}
```

```css
div[style^="background-image"]{color:red}
#id2{background-color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1" style="background-image:url(a.png);">test content</div>
<div id="id2">Test content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it without jQuery, using vanilla Javacript.

Use `window.getComputedStyle` to get the element style and check if its `background-image` is `none`, 1 by 1. Add a class `has-bk-img` to those who have background image, and then set your CSS to the class `has-bk-img`.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('div');

elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(elems);

elems.map(function(el) {
  var styles = window.getComputedStyle(el);

  var bkImg = styles.getPropertyValue("background-image");

  if (bkImg !== "none") {
    el.classList.add("has-bk-img");
  }
})
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/whrz7976/11/

Answer (score -3):

Select the div without class and id

```css
div:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">div1</div>
<div id="id2">div2</div>
```